# Listen to app being killed & do something before it is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am developing an Android app. I have a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) running in my app.

I need to handle something in service when the app is being killed. How can I listen to app being killed event? Is there **broadcast action** for this? If not, is there a way to **listen to app being killed** ???

I have a log message in `onDestroy()` callback of **MyService** , but it is not get called when I "Force stop" my app in Settings.

```
public MyService extends Service{
   ...
  @Override
  public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
     //It is not called when force stop my app from system settings
     Log.i("Debug","service is killed!"); 
  }
}
```

But I know there are some apps in google play that will be automatically restarted once it is killed by the system, how do they implement this feature then ??

Comment: I don't think so, because `Service.onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to run every time you service is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, I logged in onDestroy() but it is not get called when I force stop my app in System settings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect or receive a message prior to your app being killed. `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` are your best bets, but there is no guarantee that either of them will be called.

However, returning `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` in the `onStartCommand()` of your service will have Android restart your Service when resources are available again.

Please note that Force Stopping an app on newer versions of Android (can't remember exactly from which version, but I think ICS) will stop the process until the user starts it manually. This means that START_STICKY will have no effect if the user goes and clicks Force Stop in the settings.

Comment: Ok, so, you mean if only consider about the app process get killed by system , basically there is no way to detect this event....